# Chaining properties in C# & unexpected results

Tags: c#, .net, properties, struct, value-type

I was just having a quick read through [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2006/09/07/745085.aspx) (specifically the bit about why he chose to use structs / fields instead of classes / properties) and saw this line:

> The result of a property is not a true l-value so we cannot do something like Vertex.Normal.dx = 0.   The chaining of properties gives very unexpected results.

What sort of unexpected results is he talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add to dbemerlin's answer that the key here is Rico's note that *properties* are not "lvalues", or, as we call them in C#, "variables".

In order to mutate a mutable struct (and ideally, you should not; mutable structs often cause more problems than they solve) you need to mutate a *variable*. That's what a variable *is* -- a storage location whose contents change. If you have a field of type vector and you say

```
Foo.vector.x = 123;
```

then we have a variable of value type -- the field Foo.vector -- and we can therefore mutate its property x.  But if you have a property of value type:

```
Foo.Vector.x = 123;
```

the *property* is not a variable. This is equivalent to

```
Vector v = Foo.Vector;
v.x = 123;
```

which mutates the temporary variable v, not whatever storage location is backing the property.

The whole problem goes away if you abandon mutable value types. To change x, make a new vector with the new values and replace the whole thing:

```
Foo.Vector = new Vector(x, Foo.Vector.y);
```

Comment: I still cant see a situation where `Vector v = Foo.Vector; v.x = 123;` wouldn't do what I'm expecting it to (excluding concurrency issues & daft property implementations)

Comment: @Kragen, the assumption is that Vector is a value type and therefore copied *by value*, not a reference type copied *by reference*. That's why value types have the name they do. Local variable v is a *copy* of Foo.Vector; mutating it changes only v.

Answer (score 2):

The only "unexpected" result would be that the assignment wouldn't last because Vertex.Normal returns a copy and the code assigns 0 to dx of the copy.

I can't test it now but that is what i would expect (from what i know of .NETs handling of structs)