# Automatic Property Value Not Updated with Struct

Tags: c#

Take the following `struct` class:

```
public struct SingleWraper
{
    private double _myValue;

    public double MyValue
    {
        get { return _myValue; }
        set { _myValue = value; }
    }

    public void SetMyValue(double myValue)
    {
        _myValue = myValue;
    }
}

public struct DoubleWraper
{
    public SingleWraper SingWraper { get; set; }

    public void SetMyValue(double singleVa)
    {
        SingWraper.SetMyValue(singleVa);
    }
}
```

Run the following test:

```
    [Test]
    public void SetMyValue()
    {
        var singleWraper = new DoubleWraper();
        singleWraper.SetMyValue(10);
        Assert.AreEqual(10,singleWraper.SingWraper.MyValue);
    }
```

It fails.

However, if you ***don't*** use automatic property for `DoubleWraper`, i.e, you expand the field as below:

```
public struct DoubleWraper
{
    private SingleWraper _singWraper;
    public SingleWraper SingWraper
    {
        get { return _singWraper; }
        set { _singWraper = value; }
    }

    public void SetMyValue(double singleVa)
    {
        _singWraper.SetMyValue(singleVa);
    }
}
```

Then the test will pass.

Why this is so?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. Here's an answer from earlier this week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132594/chaining-properties-in-c-unexpected-results/2133223#2133223

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is here:

```
_singWraper.SetMyValue(singleVa);
```

vs:

```
SingWraper.SetMyValue(singleVa);
```

In the second, you access a **property**, therefore you clone the struct; essentially this is the same as:

```
var clonedAndIndependentValue = SingWraper; // getter
clonedAndIndependentValue.SetMyValue(singleVa);
```

Note we've updated a different struct value; contrast to field access, which talks to the **existing** struct value.

Yet another example of why mutable structs are evil. **DON'T DO IT**. Make the struct immutable (no `Set*` methods, property setters, or other shenanigans). Or use a class.

Comment: This is quite possibly one of the clearest examples of the dangers with mutable structs that I have seen in a while.